# get success message from an element in Selenium IDE

Tags: html, css, selenium

Is there any way to get success message from an element using Selenium IDE?

I press submit button which will generate a new page , and after submitting i will go to that page and a success message is generated.

Now i want to log the success message , because only when the success message appears, it means the action is successful executed.

I tried the following thing , but it is not working:

```
clickAndWait         css=#submitButton

assertElementPresent css=#successCreateMsg

storeVisible         css=#successCreateMsg   succssValue

echo                 $('succssValue')

What i have in the log are :

[info] Executing: |assertElementPresent | css=#successMsgPOSContractAdd | |

[info] Executing: |storeVisible | css=#successMsgPOSContractAdd | comContract |

[info] Executing: |echo | $('comContract') | |

[info] echo: $('comContract')
```

Does anyone know why echo does not print the expected message or how can i get the message?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the echo target to `${comContract}` and it will log true, if the field was visible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working, but on my side i get 'false', maybe it is related to that the success message just show few second on the page